# Adding spatially explicit edges to sfnetwork

Tags: r-sf, tidygraph, sfnetwork

I have an sfnetwork in R with spatially implicit edges. I would like to plot it using tmap, and therefore I would like to make the edges spatially explicit, by just turning them into lines.

I created this monstrosity to do it

```
edges <- activate(graph, "edges") %>% as_tibble() %>%
  inner_join(activate(graph, "nodes") %>% as_tibble(), by=c("from"="node_id")) %>%
  inner_join(activate(graph, "nodes") %>% as_tibble(), by=c("to"="node_id")) %>%
  mutate(geometry = purrr::pmap(list(geometry.x, geometry.y), st_union)) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  st_cast("MULTIPOINT") %>%
  st_cast("LINESTRING")
```

The MULTIPOINT cast may have been needed because there were self-loops in the graph, which I assume got turned into POINTs, not MULTIPOINTs, under st_union, to the dismay of the LINESTRING cast.

This seems really awkward, and it creates a separate object which I cannot glue back to the sfnetwork.

How should I do it instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following code could work to create an `sfnetwork` object with spatial explicit edges starting from an `sfnetwork` object with spatial implicit edges.

First, load packages

```r
library(sfnetworks)
library(tmap)
```

Create some fake data. The example is taken from `?sfnetwork`

```r
p1 = sf::st_point(c(7, 51))
p2 = sf::st_point(c(7, 52))
p3 = sf::st_point(c(8, 52))
nodes = sf::st_as_sf(sf::st_sfc(p1, p2, p3, crs = 4326))

e1 = sf::st_cast(sf::st_union(p1,p2), "LINESTRING")
e2 = sf::st_cast(sf::st_union(p1,p3), "LINESTRING")
e3 = sf::st_cast(sf::st_union(p2,p3), "LINESTRING")
edges = sf::st_as_sf(sf::st_sfc(e1, e2, e3, crs = 4326))
edges$from = c(1, 1, 2)
edges$to = c(2, 3, 3)
```

Create network with spatially implicit edges

```r
(my_sfnetwork <- sfnetwork(nodes, edges, directed = FALSE, edges_as_lines = FALSE))
#> # An sfnetwork with 3 nodes and 3 edges
#> #
#> # CRS:  EPSG:4326 
#> #
#> # An undirected simple graph with 1 component with spatially implicit edges
#> #
#> # Node Data:     3 x 1 (active)
#> # Geometry type: POINT
#> # Dimension:     XY
#> # Bounding box:  xmin: 7 ymin: 51 xmax: 8 ymax: 52
#>             x
#>   <POINT [°]>
#> 1      (7 51)
#> 2      (7 52)
#> 3      (8 52)
#> #
#> # Edge Data: 3 x 2
#>    from    to
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1     1     2
#> 2     1     3
#> 3     2     3
```

Make edges spatially explicit

```r
(my_sfnetwork <- tidygraph::convert(
  my_sfnetwork, 
  to_spatial_explicit_edges, 
  .clean = TRUE
))
#> # An sfnetwork with 3 nodes and 3 edges
#> #
#> # CRS:  EPSG:4326 
#> #
#> # An undirected simple graph with 1 component with spatially explicit edges
#> #
#> # Node Data:     3 x 1 (active)
#> # Geometry type: POINT
#> # Dimension:     XY
#> # Bounding box:  xmin: 7 ymin: 51 xmax: 8 ymax: 52
#>             x
#>   <POINT [°]>
#> 1      (7 51)
#> 2      (7 52)
#> 3      (8 52)
#> #
#> # Edge Data:     3 x 3
#> # Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> # Dimension:     XY
#> # Bounding box:  xmin: 7 ymin: 51 xmax: 8 ymax: 52
#>    from    to                x
#>   <int> <int> <LINESTRING [°]>
#> 1     1     2     (7 51, 7 52)
#> 2     1     3     (7 51, 8 52)
#> 3     2     3     (7 52, 8 52)
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Check [here](https://luukvdmeer.github.io/sfnetworks/articles/morphers.html), `?tidygraph::convert` and `?to_spatial_explicit_edges` for more details.